# Oracle - correlated subquery problems

Tags: sql, oracle, analytics, correlated-subquery

I have this query:

```
select acc_num
from (select distinct ac_outer.acc_num, ac_outer.owner
       from ac_tab ac_outer
       where (ac_outer.owner = '1234567')
             and ac_outer.owner = (select sq.owner
                                      from (select a1.owner
                                             from ac_tab a1
                                             where a1.acc_num = ac_outer.acc_num /*This is the line that gives me problems.*/
                                             order by a1.a_date desc, a1.b_date desc, a1.c_date desc) sq
                                      where rownum = 1)
       order by dbms_random.value()) subq
order by acc_num;
```

The idea is to get all `acc_num`s (not a primary key) from `ac_tab`, that have an `owner` of `1234567`.

Since an `acc_num` in `ac_tab` could have changed `owner`s over time, I am trying to use the inner correlated subqueries to ensure that an `acc_num` is returned ONLY if it's *most recent* `owner` is `12345678`. Naturally, it doesn't work (or I wouldn't be posting here ;) )

Oracle gives me an error: `ORA-000904 ac_outer.acc_num is an invalid identifier`.

I thought that `ac_outer` should be visible to the correlated subqueries, but for some reason it's not. Is there a way to fix the query, or do I have to resort to PL/SQL to solve this?

(Oracle verison is 10g)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure why Peter is using a Min(owner) analytic function instead of first_value(owner).  I believe the latter gives you what you need while the min(owner) is giving you the "minimum" owner.  Everything else in the query I agree with:

```
Select Distinct acc_num
From (
      Select
            acc_num,
            owner,
            first_value(owner) Over ( Partition By acc_num
                  Order By a_date Desc, b_date Desc, c_date Desc
                ) recent_owner
      From ac_tab
     )
Where owner = '1234567'
      And owner = recent_owner
Order By acc_num;
```

Comment: I need to do a little more analysis on the results, but this seems to be giving me what I want. I really need to learn more about analytic functions!

Answer (score 4):

I don't see what you need the `dbms_random.value()` for, but the following query using [analytic functions](http://www.psoug.org/reference/analytic_functions.html) should give you the expected result:

```
Select Distinct acc_num
From (
  Select
    acc_num,
    owner,
    First_Value(owner) Over ( Partition By acc_num
                              Order By a_date Desc, b_date Desc, c_date Desc
                            ) recent_owner
  From ac_tab
)
Where owner = '1234567'
  And owner = recent_owner
Order By acc_num;
```

The sub-query gives you the owner and the most recent owner per `acc_num`, which can then be compared in the outer query.

Comment: Ignore the `dbms_random.value()`, I was testing something else with that. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're losing scope on the "AC_OUTER" alias by nesting two deep with your subquery.  I obviously don't know your schema, but would rely on max(date) over any sorting operation and rownum.  Why don't you try something like this:

```
select ac_outer.acc_num, ac_outer.owner, max(a1.adate), max(a1.b_date), max(a1.c_date)
from   ac_tab "AC_OUTER"
where  ac_outer.owner = '1234567'
group by ac_outer.owner, ac_outer.acc_num;
```

Comment: You are correct, out of scope because more than 1 level. This is why the code won't run as-is.

Comment: You mean that I should substitute the innermost query with this one? Not sure how to integrate this into the rest of the query (And running it on its own does not give the right result). I think you're definitely right about the scoping issue though, but I had expected that all the outer queries would be visible to the innermost query, but it looks like a nested query is only visible to the query nested directly in it.

Answer (score 1):

you should use oracle analytical function to do this using partition by

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your ordered subqueries with one NOT EXISTS, that checks if there are some other owners at a later date.